# Suppress waypoint marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a path with a single waypoint. I want to hide the waypoint marker (the white circle), but at the same time I want to preserve the two endpoints markers.

I read about suppressing all the markers by means of the `suppressMarker` option and then adding each marker manually, but this way I'm missing the default labelled icons.

None of the icons that I've found on the Internet looks exactly like the default ones (the green A and red B pins).

The question is: how can I suppress only the waypoint marker, otherwise how can I use the default directions icons for the two endpoints?

Comment: So you want to use DirectionsService with a waypoint but not display the waypoint marker. Is that what you want?

Comment: Check this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685974/how-to-replace-a-and-b-markers-in-google-map-api

Comment: @MrUpsidown Yes, that's it! The problem with your Q&A is that I don't know how to get the default endpoints icons.

Comment: **Google API**: https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/dynamic_icons (Warning: deprecated). **Styled marker**: https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries **MapIcons collection**: http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/numbers-letters/letters/?style=default

Comment: @MrUpsidown thank you for your comments. Unfortunately, as I wrote, I'm searching for the actual default directions markers and not for any endpoint marker. At the moment, the only solution which comes to mind is to define two directions with the same endpoints: the first with the path displayed and the markers hidden (for the real path) and the second with the path hidden and the markers displayed (just for the markers).